# Issue with Ajax changing image Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a rails app and am using the `acts_as_votable` gem for likes/unlikes.

A Post can be liked or unliked.

I am using ajax to update the like count without reloading the page and it is working fine, although I am trying to make it so that when the 'like' button is clicked, the image source changes.

Currently this only works for the 'unlike' button but for some reason not for the like button.

Here is my `_votes` partial:

```
<% if current_user.liked? post %>
    <%= link_to unlike_post_path(post), remote: true, method: :put, class: 'unlike' do %>
        <%= image_tag("/assets/like.png", id: "like") %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to like_post_path(post), remote: true, method: :put, class: 'like' do %>
        <%= image_tag("/assets/heart.png", id: "heart") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my `index.html.erb` (minified):

```
<span id="likes_<%= post.id %>">
  <%= post.cached_votes_up %>
    <% if post.cached_votes_up == 1 %>
        like
    <% else %>
        likes
    <% end %>
</span>
```

Here is my `like.js.erb`:

```
$('.like').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $('#likes_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @post.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');
    $("#heart").attr("src", "/assets/like.png");
});
```

Here is my `unlike.js.erb`:

```
$('.unlike').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $('#likes_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @post.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');
    $("#like").attr("src", "/assets/heart.png");
});
```

As you can see, both ajax files are similar, but only the `unlike.js.erb` one actually changes the image.

I have made sure all the image paths are correct and everything, I am just not sure why the `#heart` image isnt changing to the `like.png` image?

Comment: first `$('#likes_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @post.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');` should be `$('#like_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @post.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');`, it shld be `like_` not `likes_`

Comment: My bad @Sravan, I forgot to add this: I have a span `<span id="likes_<%= post.id %>">`, so that is where that data is going to, not to the `link_to`. I edited the question

Comment: ok, is it coming inside `ajax_success` and span id is changing? check `console.log` once.

Comment: It is just getting the new value of votes for the post, and appending it to the `<span id="likes_<%= post.id %>">`. But this works fine. The issue I am having is with the like image not changing

Comment: just `alert('test')` inside success function and check if it is entering there?

Comment: Just did that and yes, the alert works perfectly. I am not sure why the image isn't though..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129505/discussion-between-sravan-and-dingo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have **many posts** and the **id** may be in two or more places,

`$("#heart").attr("src", "/assets/like.png");` may not work fine

**You should refer each image with a specific id**

Instead, use **`$("#heart_<%= @post.id %>").attr("src", "/assets/like.png");`**

**your html be like:**

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), remote: true, method: :put, class: 'like' do %>
    <%= image_tag("/assets/heart.png", id: "heart_#{post.id}") %>
<% end %>
```

**your js.erb is:**

```
$('.like').bind('ajax:success', function() {
    $('#likes_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript @post.get_upvotes.size.to_s %>');
    $("#heart_<%= @post.id %>").attr("src", "/assets/like.png");
});
```